# Can't retrieve local data (pinned objects) from Parse Local Datastore

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, datastore

I can't retrieve the local data (pinned objects) after re-open the app.

I have this code in my controller:

```
- (IBAction)btnAddTouched:(id)sender
{
    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Foobar"];

    [object setValue:[[NSDate date] description] forKey:@"data"];

    [object pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Pinned OK");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Erro: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}

- (IBAction)btnLoadTouched:(id)sender
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Foobar"];

    [query fromLocalDatastore];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Erro: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Pin some objects with `btnAddTouched:`;
2. Close the app (stop debbuging);
3. Open the app again (build again);
4. Try Load pinned data with `btnLoadTouched`;

It is retrieving me a object with `localId: (null)`:

```
"<Foobar: 0x15d42770, objectId: new, localId: (null)> {\n    data = \"2014-12-15 21:00:05 +0000\";\n}"
    )
```

And after that the `pinInBackgroundWithBlock:` won't work anymore. The blocks is never called then.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you create a PFObject locally, and never properly save it to the cloud, the objectId is never set, which is what you see here. Seems elementary, unless i am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parse iOS SDK release 1.6.1 fixed this bug.

Comment: I am having similar issue. [Please see Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578437/pointers-data-not-storing-in-local-database-parse-ios) . I have updated with the latest version v1.6.1, but still same issue

Comment: sorry to add another "me too" comment, but i'm seeing the same issue. pinned objects are not being found in the local datastore. i'm using the latest parse sdk.