# Pointers data not storing in local database parse ios

Tags: ios, debugging, parse-platform, sdk, local-datastore

I have a query with many includeKeys which are pointers to another class. After receiving the data from parse cloud all the records are getting stored locally using **pinAll** method. When I fetch back the results stored, I can able to get the records but not pointers included. See sample code below

```
[query includeKey:@"classOne.innerClass"];
[query includeKey:@"classTwo.innerClass"];
[query includeKey:@"classThree"];
[query includeKey:@"classFour"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
   [PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects withName:@"LocalRecords" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

   }];
}];
```

And I am fetching the records like

```
PFQuery *lquery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[ClassName parseClassName]];
   [lquery fromPinWithName:@"LocalRecords"];
   BFTask *btask = [[lquery findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
            return task;
        }
   }];
```

When I try to access any of the columns in classOne, classTwo, classThree and classFour I am getting an exception **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "name" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'**

Comment: Before you can fetch from the local database, you have to tell the query where it needs to look `[query fromLocalDatastore];`

Comment: I am already using this..... No luck

Comment: I'm interested to know more about this issue as well. What version of the iOS SDK did you test this against?

Comment: And what's your milage with http://stackoverflow.com/a/27586395/590767?

Comment: @fatuhoku I am working with the latest environment. xcode 6 with iOS8.

Comment: and this issue is fixed with the latest parse SDK(v1.6.1).

Comment: @san, I am not able to fetch using v1.6.2. When I include any key then it gives me 0 objects else gives all. Seems not fixed even in recent version.

Comment: @ShivaReddy, You are right. There is an active thread about this issue [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1771368209755734/)

Comment: Actual issue is different from this. Calling includKey for the local query(**lquery**) solves the above issue.

Comment: I did [lquery includeKey:@"category"]; but when I do this not able fetch any objects the count is 0, but if I remove and and make a query getting all (26 currently stored) objects but without pointers.

Comment: Ensure that you don't have any dangling pointers in your class(which you are including).

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the Parse.com local data store functionality for iOS.

From the 1.6.3 release notes:

> "Improved consistency of Local Datastore / Parse queries with includeKey: and NSNull values."